# show value highest checkbox

Tags: php, html

I want to find the group of checkbox that user tick the most to something else
please help me!
Thanks.

**Here my HTML**

```
<form method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="group_1[]" value="V1"/>V1
<input type="checkbox" name="group_1[]" value="V2"/>V2
<input type="checkbox" name="group_1[]" value="V3"/>V3
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="group_2[]" value="V4"/>V4
<input type="checkbox" name="group_2[]" value="V5"/>V5
<input type="checkbox" name="group_2[]" value="V6"/>V6
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="group_3[]" value="V7"/>V7
<input type="checkbox" name="group_3[]" value="V8"/>V8
<input type="checkbox" name="group_3[]" value="V9"/>V9
<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$group_1 = count($_POST['group_1']);
$group_2 = count($_POST['group_2']);
$group_3 = count($_POST['group_3']);

if ($group_1 > $group_2 and $group_1 > $group_3) {
    echo "Group 1 is highest ";
}

elseif ($group_2 > $group_1 and $group_2 > $group_3) {
    echo "Group 2 is highest ";
}

elseif ($group_3 > $group_1 and $group_3 > $group_2) {
    echo "Group 3 is highest ";
 }
}
?>
```

i'm new in php so I code "If Else" but i don't want to use this. and one more i don't want to code specific like "$group_1 = count($_POST['group_1']);" i just want to define "name of checkbox" to get value.
all i want is get same result but different code.

Comment: Sorry but the question is unclear for me. You want to define "name of checkbox"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the max() function to get highest value

Please refer to http://php.net/max

Probably like this:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$group_1 = count($_POST['group_1']);
$group_2 = count($_POST['group_2']);
$group_3 = count($_POST['group_3']);

$array = array("Group 1"=>$group_1,"Group 2"=>$group_2,"Group 3"=>$group_3);

$maxIndex = array_search(max($array), $array);
echo $maxIndex;


}
?>
```